# EF6(not EF core) using Navigation property instead of Linq joins

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two tables that I need to join and filter. Orders and Customers. I have generated these classes using EF Code First from DB.

Generated classes for the tables -

**Orders**

```
    [Table("Orders")]
    public partial class Orders
    {
      
        [Key]
        [StringLength(17)]
        public string OrderID { get; set; }

        public int ShipToCustomerID { get; set; }

        //Navigation Property 
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

**Customers**

```
[Table("Customer")]
    public partial class Customer
    {
       
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }


        //Navigation prop

        public int ShipToCustomerID { get; set; } (not a part of the table, just attempting to get the navigation work)

        public Orders Order { get; set; }
   }
```

**Method 1:**

LINQ Joins

```
using (var context = new OrderDetailsGeneral1())
     {
        var data = (from p in context.Orders
                    join q in context.Customers 
                    on p.ShipToCustomerID equals q.CustomerID
                    where p.OrderID == "7150615"
                    select new
                         {
                             OrderID = p.OrderID,
                             CustomerID = q.AccountNumber
                         }
                     );

    var orders = data.ToList();
    return Json(orders);
 }
```

This works well and I get the following output -

```
[
    {
        "OrderID": "7150615",
        "CustomerID": "23320347       "
    }
]
```

**Method 2:**
I read that it's better to use navigation properties than using joins and that's why I was trying to do so, as per that I added the navigation properties to the classes above.

I tried a bunch of ways to link them together. One of them is the way mentioned here and I came across a bunch of errors.

It would try to map Customers.CustomerID to Orders.OrderID instead of Orders.ShipToCustomerID.

What's the best way to achieve this? I am having a hard time figuring out linking this foreign key (Customers.CustomerID) to a non primary/alternate key (Orders.ShipToCustomerID)

Comment: If those class definitions were generated by EF then I suspect one issue is that the FK between orders and customers was not defined in your database. (I.e. the field is there, but the database is not configured to use it as an actual referential FK.) Customer should have a `virtual ICollection<Order> Orders ` property not a singular Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fix your classes

```
    [Table("Orders")]
    public partial class Order
    {
      
        [Key]
        [StringLength(17)]
        public string OrderID { get; set; }

        public int ShipToCustomerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(ShipToCustomerID))]
        [InverseProperty("Orders")]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }



   [Table("Customer")]
    public partial class Customer
    {
       [Key]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
         public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Order.Customer))]
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Sweet, this worked. Yes, as you suspected there's no FK relationship in the Database. So if I had to add a third table in the relationship (Orders-Tracking), I'd do the same ForeignKey - InverseProperty thing?

Comment: Yes, you can  try. If you have a problem let me know

Comment: How can I apply the same logic to join two tables on any random columns(non pk)? And also add a filter on the join. any good resource to learn Navigation Properties would be a great help as well.

Comment: You can't use it for random columns. It works only for foreign keys. To join using random columns you can try the syntax you are using in your posted question.